# Show post counts for every day of week in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function in my controller with this:

```
$one_week_ago = Carbon::now()->subDays(6)->format('Y-m-d');
$dates = Post::where('created_at', '>=', $one_week_ago)
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
        ->get(array(
             DB::raw('Date(created_at) as date'),
             DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "count"')
          ));

return view ('analytics', array('dates' => $dates));
```

And my view is:

```
@foreach ($dates as $date => $count) 
      <p> {{ $date . '->' . $count }}</p>
@endforeach
```

I am getting the output as:

```
0 -> {"date":"2017-04-07","count":7}

1 -> {"date":"2017-04-08","count":2}

2 -> {"date":"2017-04-12","count":4}

3 -> {"date":"2017-04-13","count":1}
```

**Problem:**
The dates in which has no posts (i.e postscount = 0) those are not shown.
Example: 2017-04-09, 2017-04-10 and 2017-04-11 are not shown.

But I want the output for those dates as count:0

Comment: You need to mask your output by having a default array. I would do that on the client side. What is the range of dates?

Comment: `Carbon::now()->subDays(6)` this gives me a week before date. So date range is of 7 days (a week)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach to tackle this is to build a collection containing the default values first (keys are the dates you're looking at, and the values are 0). This gives you an array that looks like this:

```
[
    '2017-04-07' => 0,
    '2017-04-08' => 0,
    '2017-04-09' => 0,
    '2017-04-10' => 0,
    '2017-04-11' => 0,
    '2017-04-12' => 0,
    '2017-04-13' => 0,
]
```

Then we take the posts we found and call `pluck` - this lets us specify the value we want (`count`) and the key we'd like to use (`date`). This won't necessarily have all of the days we want in it, and will look something like this:

```
[
    '2017-04-07' => 12,
    '2017-04-10' => 3,
    '2017-04-11' => 7,
]
```

Finally, we merge the two based on the keys, using the first collection as the base. This means we get to keep all the default values we set up (and more importantly, all 7 dates we set) and it just overwrites individual day values with the results from the database.

---

Here's the final code:

```
// Build an array of the dates we want to show, oldest first
$dates = collect();
foreach( range( -6, 0 ) AS $i ) {
    $date = Carbon::now()->addDays( $i )->format( 'Y-m-d' );
    $dates->put( $date, 0);
}

// Get the post counts
$posts = Post::where( 'created_at', '>=', $dates->keys()->first() )
             ->groupBy( 'date' )
             ->orderBy( 'date' )
             ->get( [
                 DB::raw( 'DATE( created_at ) as date' ),
                 DB::raw( 'COUNT( * ) as "count"' )
             ] )
             ->pluck( 'count', 'date' );

// Merge the two collections; any results in `$posts` will overwrite the zero-value in `$dates`
$dates = $dates->merge( $posts );

return view( 'analytics', compact( 'dates' ) );
```

Your view then should simply be

```
@foreach ( $dates as $date => $count ) 
    <p> {{ $date }} = {{ $count }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: With this I am getting all the dates but the count is 0 for all the dates. Any solution for this?

Comment: @thehackwall I made a little bit of a booboo in the original version; I've edited the post to explain myself a bit better and quickly tested the code in a Laravel project I've got open. It should be good now

Comment: I am still getting count:0 for every dates.
Can i pass variable posts in an array to the view? Because I have multiple variables to pass like `return view ('analytics', array('count_posts' => $count_posts, 'count_users' => $count_users, 'today' =>$today, 'dates' => $dates));`
**Awesome explanation btw**

Comment: @thehackwall have a look at the documentation for [compact](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php). You could also just use an array exactly like you described if you wanted to. For the `count: 0`, have you got `$dates = $dates->merge( $posts )`? Originally I missed the `$dates = ` on the front of it, which you need

Comment: Yes i have pasted the above exact code for the controller function and the view. (Except for the compact thing, I have passed dates in an array)

Comment: Oh I did a silly mistake over there. Now I am getting the correct OP. Thanks Joe :)

Comment: Thanks for this. but in your `$posts` query you have already return `date` with `count` by `pluck('count', 'date')`, for me it seems no need to further merge the `$dates` and `$posts` collections.

Comment: @seedme quite possibly - it's 3 years since I wrote it so it may not be my best code ever :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your function

```
for ($i=0; $i<=6; $i++) {
   $dates[] = Carbon::now()->subDays($i)->format('Y-m-d');
}

$data = Post::whereIn('created_at', $dates)
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
        ->get(array(
             DB::raw('Date(created_at) as date'),
             DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "count"')
          ))
->keyBy('date');

return view ('analytics', array('dates' => $dates, 'data' => $data));
```

And view

```
@foreach ($dates as $date) 
      <p> {{ $date . '->' . isset($data[$date]) ? $data[$date] : 0; }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Be carefull with data vs date

Comment: Okay there are some typos in your code :p but i managed to fix that.
Now i am getting an error in my view as: `Undefined index: 2017-04-13 (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\awesome-meme\resources\views\analytics.blade.php)`

Answer (score 0):

> @foreach ($dates as $date => $count)
>
> {{ $date . '->' . $count }}
>
> @endforeach

The "$date => $count" thing acts as $key => value and wont return you the result in desired format.

Since your data is a JSON object, you can show it as

```
@foreach ($data as $row) 
  <p> {{ $row['date'] . '->' . $row['count'] }}</p>
@endforeach
```

or

```
@foreach ($data as $row) 
  <p> {{ $row->date . '->' . $row->count }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: His result data is an array, not a PHP object or JSON object. Even using the fix you suggested though, he'd be missing any date that has `0` posts